# Unity - Admob shows only real ads, even when trying to test

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I'm trying to use my `AdManager` class that shows banner like so:

```
public static void ShowBanner()
{
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
            .AddTestDevice("MY_DEVICE_ID").Build();
    if (bannerAd != null)
    {
        bannerAd.Destroy();
    }

    bannerAd = new BannerView(bannerID, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Top);
    bannerAd.LoadAd(request);
}
```

And I have the `Interstitial ads` called:

```
public static void ShowVideo()
{
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)
            .AddTestDevice("MY_DEVICE_ID").Build();
    if (interst != null)
    {
        interst.Destroy();
    }

    interst = new InterstitialAd(videoID);
    interst.LoadAd(request);
    if (interst.IsLoaded())
    {
        interst.Show();
    }
}
```

Of course I have some viable `string` instead of "MY_DEVICE_ID" in the appropriate section. I got that by downloading an app named "Device ID" from Google Play and put the ID I got into the string. `bannerID` and `videoID` are viable strings as well, I got them by creating my admob account, though I don't have the app uploaded to Play yet.

The issue is that to my best knowledge this should only show me some test ads, but it actually gives me real ads when trying to use it on my tablet.

Note that I deploy by clicking "Build" inside Unity, copy the `.apk` to my device and install it.

What could cause the issue? In case of a wrong device ID it just gives real ads? How to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure you are using test ads, it's the safest to actually use [this method](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#sample_ad_units) here.

It's basically that you use the following IDs for ads:

- Banner

ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111

- Interstitial

ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712

- Rewarded Video

ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917

- Native Advanced

ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110

- Native Express

(Small template): ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2793859312

(Large template): ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2177258514

Instead of your own ad IDs.